# Terraform Remote State - use variables which are not present during plan/apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a question regarding terraform remote states. Maybe I am using the remote state wrong or there is another possible solution:

In my scripts I create a db instance. The created endpoint, port etc. should be saved in the remote state. The DB scripts are outsourced in a module.

I want to reuse the endpoint and port values and pass them to the docker container environment:

```
environment = [
    {
      name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL",
      value: "jdbc:postgresql://${data.terraform_remote_state.foo.outputs.db_endpoint}:${data.terraform_remote_state.foo.outputs.db_port}"
    }
```

These scripts are also outsourced into a separate module.

On each first run terraform states that these values are not present. Therefor I have to outcomment the environment values, run `terraform apply` and after all was created, I have to rerun terraform apply - now with the values for the environment.

Is there another possible (and better solution) to pass the created db values to the service and task which contains the docker container environment?

Comment: By the way, maybe I rushed with my answer and should this question first, but why you use `terraform_remote_state`? Because I presume `terraform apply` created resource referenced by `terraform_remote_state`, so I'm not seeing the reason to use it. Don't forget that you can create output in the `module` and reference it by `module.alias.output_name` and pass it to the environment variable. Anyway, it would be helpful if you could provide minimal reproducible example

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Didn't know about the possibility to use the `module.` prefix. It worked. Have a great weekend

Comment: PS: update your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 21-05-2021**

I suggested @smsnheck that if a `module` block is used, one can reference output variable via `module.module_name.output_name`. E.g:

`module/main.tf`

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  // Arguments taken from example
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
}

output "db_host" {
  value = aws_db_instance.example.address
}

output "db_port" {
  value = aws_db_instance.example.port
}
```

`main.tf`

```
module "db" {
  source = "./module"
}

// ...

resource "some_docker_provider" "example" {
// ...
  environment = [
    {
      name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL",
      value: "jdbc:postgresql://${module.db.db_host}:${module.db.db_port}"
    }
  ]
// ...
}
```

**Old answer**

---

I presume that you are creating the database from the terraform scripts. If so, you should not use `data`, because `data` is read **before** any resource is created. So what's happening is you are trying to get information about db host and port before it is created.

Assuming you are creating DB instance with `aws_db_instance`, you should reference to the port and host like this:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  // Arguments taken from example
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
}

// ...

// Locals are not required, you may use aws_db_instance.example. values directly
locals {
  db_host = aws_db_instance.example.address
  db_port = aws_db_instance.example.port
}

// ...

resource "some_docker_provider" "example" {
// ...
  environment = [
    {
      name: "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL",
      value: "jdbc:postgresql://${local.db_host}:${local.db_port}"
    }
  ]
// ...
}
```

This way, Terraform will know that first a DB instance must be created, because `.address` and `.port` are the values, that are known **after** a DB instance is created (a DB instance will be now the dependency of the docker container).

To get more information about the values that are returned after creation of the resource, refer to the `Attributes reference` in the provider's documentation. For instance, here is the reference for `aws_db_instance`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#attributes-reference